# ExtJs 4.2 - Html editor tooltip issue in IE 9

Tags: extjs

Tool tip seems broken for Html Editors in IE 9 browser. Is there a way to fix this?

Fiddle here: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4bv (Issue only on IE 9)

[image: tooltip text overlaps tooltip bubble]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disable compatibility view**, this will solve the problem. **Add the following meta tag** to your page html header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />
```

It will **force IE to render** the page **on IE 9 Mode** despite the general browser options, **[here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)** the full detail on the options for compatibility view meta tags.
You can disable compatibility view manually also to test the differences between both rendering modes, such as follows (here's a **[KB entry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2536204)** on the subject)

[image: Tooltip layout with compatibility view **disabled**]
[image: Tooltip layout with compatibility view **enabled**]

Hope this solve your problem.